# JavaScript HTML5 in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, shapes

I made a shape with html5, it looks like a surfboard.
code:

```
    <script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100, 5);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(50,5,-50,300,50,505);
ctx.lineTo(150,505);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(250,300,150,0,100,5);

img = new Image()
img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(this, "repeat");
        ctx.fill();
    }, true);
    
ctx.lineWidth = 5;  
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();


img.src= "<?php echo $uploadfile ?>" 

    </script>
```

Now my question is, I got multiple images stored in my database (only the image path).

Now I want to show all images which I have stored in my database to show in this shape.
So my shape is a surfboard, and now I want multiple surfboards next to each other.

```
<?php
    dbConn();

    $q_select_images = mysql_query("select * from orders");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q_select_images))
    {
         print "<img src=\"/test/". $row['image'] . "\" />";
        
    }
    
    closeDbConn();
    ?>
```

This code above is to show all the images which I stored in my database.
How do I combine these 2 scripts.

because by just putting the JavaScript code in the while{ } function doesn't work.
I want to repeat the shape with each time another image.

please help me, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why not output an (JSON-compliant) _Array_?

Comment: i dont know what u mean, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab all image paths first and put them in a JavaScript array:

```
$images = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q_select_images)) {
     $images[] = $row['image'];
}
```

Then add this JavaScript code:

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>,
body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

for (var i = 0, n = images.length; i < n; ++i) {
    myImageFn(body, images[i]);
}

function myImageFn(container, path)
{
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.style.width = '200px';
    c.style.height = '510px';

    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100, 5);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(50,5,-50,300,50,505);
    ctx.lineTo(150,505);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(250,300,150,0,100,5);

    img = new Image()
    img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(this, "repeat");
            ctx.fill();
        }, true);

    ctx.lineWidth = 5;  
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    img.src = path;

    container.appendChild(c);
}
```

For each image you still have to add them to the DOM though.

Comment: i understand what ur saying with "You can grab all image paths first and put them in a JavaScript array:"    

but i dont understand: "For each image you still have to add them to the DOM though"

Comment: the javascript code is separated, it just shows img.src= "<?php echo $uploadfile ?>"..   $uploadfile = the path of an image, this can also be img.src="images/image.jpg"          this is the code for just showing an image in the shape that i made with HTML 5.     the php code,   just shows all the images i have stored in my database,    now i want to combine it to show all images that i have stored in my database to show in this shape next to each other

Comment: @user2257604 Well, your canvas always references the id `myCanvas`; if I understand it right, you will want to have a canvas for each image you have.

Comment: yes, so i want to repeat my canvas, with all the images i have stored in my database

Comment: <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="510"></canvas>    this bit of code i forget to post, but i use this line aswell

Comment: @user2257604 Okay, updated my answer; it now creates a new canvas each time and adds it to your `<body>` tag.

Comment: It begins to work, but it dont uses the canvas size i have set.

Comment: @user2257604 I've added that in the code as well ... but perhaps `.style.width` and `.style.height` only works after it has been added to DOM.

Comment: the size is right now, only thing is he doesnt make the shape that size, he just stretch it to that size

Comment: @user2257604 Not sure why that is.

Comment: when i change:var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.style.width = '200px';
    c.style.height = '510px';

into:"var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");

it's shows the right sizes but it only shows 1

Comment: @user2257604 Do you have any other CSS that styles the canvas tag?

Comment: Cant i just use my old code, but in a for loop with the sql query, so that i only have to change the last line "img.src = "

Comment: @user2257604 No, because then you would only see one image again. You could add a class to your canvas to size it using CSS; `c.className = 'mycanvasclass'` and style accordingly.

Comment: Jack u have been very helpfull en very patient. but this is to much for me, i dont got enough knowledge of it all

Comment: I already thought about that but this also didnt work, it just stretch it and not give it the size/resolution i want

Comment: @user2257604 Why don't you fiddle with this a bit more and try to work it out on your own :) you're almost there anyway.

Comment: i will try some, thnx for making some time to help me :)